# Postgres 8.1 pg_trgm plugin doesn't work with unicode chars

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to get the pg_trgm plugin in postgres server 8.1 to work with unicode chars?

Answer (score 1):

No, that functionality was added in PostgreSQL 8.4, so you need to upgrade. Unless you want to back-patch the functionality yourself and have your own branch of 8.1.